# Streaming audio from parse in Swift 3

Tags: swift, parse-platform, avplayer, back4app

I'm using Back4app as Parse server
I'm trying to stream audio from Prase 
everything works fine , but if I click on any index (except index 0) on tableview I got error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

I don't know why when I click on Index 0 it work fine but any other index I got error !

```
func grabSong() {        
    let SongQuery = PFQuery(className: "Songs")

    SongQuery.getObjectInBackground(withId:iDArray[SelectedSongNumber!] ,block: { (object : PFObject?, error : Error?) ->  Void in           
        if let AudioFileURLTemp : PFFile = object?.value(forKey: "SongFile") as? PFFile {            
            print(AudioFileURLTemp)

            audioP = AVPlayer(url: NSURL(string: AudioFileURLTemp.url!) as! URL)            
            audioP.play()        
        }       
    })
}
```

I got the error on this line:

```
audioP = AVPlayer(url: NSURL(string: AudioFileURLTemp.url!) as! URL)
```

Comment: Check piece by piece: `AudioFileURLTemp.url`, then `NSURL(string: AudioFileURLTemp.url!) as! URL`. If you use Swift 3, do you have to switch between `NSURL` & `URL`?

Comment: I think so , if I delete (as! URL) I got this error "Cannot convert value of type 'NSURL?' to expected argument type 'URL" and suggest me to add as! URL .... I also check AudioFileURLTemp.url it give me different song link depend on which index I clicked

Comment: Can't you use `URL(string:AudioFileURLTemp.url!)`?

Comment: I can use " audioP = AVPlayer(url: URL(string:AudioFileURLTemp.url!)!) "  but I got same problem ,first index working fine the rest I got same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why I got the error. It's because some of the song names have spaces in them, but the first song doesn't have any spaces in its names. So I tried to copy the link in the browser and see how the browser deals with spaces. I found out it replaces spaces with %20.

So I replaced every space with "%20" and now it works.

Correct code

```
func grabSong() {        
    let SongQuery = PFQuery(className: "Songs")
    SongQuery.getObjectInBackground(withId:iDArray[SelectedSongNumber] ,block: { (object : PFObject?, error : Error?) ->  Void in                    
        if let AudioFileURLTemp : PFFile = object?.value(forKey: "SongFile") as? PFFile {                       
            var songID = AudioFileURLTemp.url!.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")

            audioP = AVPlayer(url: URL(string:songID)!)
            audioP.play()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Swift has a built-in function for this: `.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlPathAllowed)`

The advantage of this is that it will handle other invalid characters that might end up in a song name, such as accented characters like "é"

There also are a few different options for the character set that you can use.